# 'arange' not defined when importing numpy

Tags: python, numpy, import

I have a function in another file that uses the Numpy function `arange` i.e.

```
import numpy as np

def plot_2D_boundary(plot_range, points, decisionfcn, labels, values =[0]):
    x = np.arange(plot_range[0], plot_range[1], .1)
```

I'm calling this function from another file in a Jupyter notebook i.e.

```
import numpy as np
plot_2D_boundary([-6,6,-6,6],[class_1,class_2],classify,[1,-1])
```

For some reason, I'm getting an error `NameError: name 'arange' is not defined` when in fact I have imported numpy in both files. What am I doing wrong when it comes to the import?

Comment: Please add the exception stacktrace. Does it reproduce if you call the 1st file? Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this seems suspect, as `np.arange` should give you an `AttributeError` (`np has no Attribute arange`) if it's truly missing. Are you sure you're using `np.arange` rather than just `arange`?

Answer (score 2):

just use

```
np.arange([start],stop,[step])
```

or like this

```
np.arange(0,5,1)
```

`0,1,2,3,4,5`